# LinkedIn OAuth API with PHP

Tags: linkedin-api

In order to save user data in the database, I'm trying to add a LinkedIn account login functionality to my PHP login page. I've found a number of articles that discuss using the `r_liteprofile` and `r_emailaddress` permissions, but they don't appear at all on my LinkedIn account page.

This picture

[image]

shows the permissions that have been added to my account, which differs from most articles.

Any assistance with utilizing those permissions would be greatly valued.

Comment: It's unclear what this has to do with PHP directly. From the (minimal) info posted so far, it appears to be an issue with your linkedin configuration. See also [ask], and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). As you're new please also take the [tour] to learn how stackoverflow works. You can [edit] your post to clarify it. Thanks.